# Limited options for Azure Storage Lifecycle Management?

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-data-lake-gen2, archiving

I'm looking to setup a Lifecycle Management rule in Azure Storage account to move blobs to an Archive storage account after X days.

**When I go to create the rule, the only option is to `Delete the blob`:**

[image]

**In [these docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-lifecycle-management-concepts?tabs=azure-portal&WT.mc_id=docs-azuredevtips-azureappsdev#azure-portal-list-view), I see options like `Move to cool storage`, etc.:**

[image]

**How do I enable these options?**

**Setup:**

- ADLS Gen 2
- Hierarchical Namespaces enabled
- Standard performance / Hot access tier
- RA-GRS replication

Answer (score 0):

Aha! Selecting `Append Blobs` checkbox disables all options other than `Delete the blob`.

[image]

Append Blobs are not allowed to be moved to Cold / Archived storage using the current Lifecycle Management blade.